# goaccess nginx log IP lookup

Tags: nginx, geoip, goaccess

I am using the latest version of goaccess (0.6) to analyze nginx log. The program seems to be parsing the file OK, since I am getting the host IPs, statistics etc. But the geoip is either not working, or I am not able to figure out how to get to the details page for hosts. As you can see, it is linking geoip

```
ldd -r /usr/local/bin/goaccess
..
libGeoIP.so.1 => /usr/lib/libGeoIP.so.1 (0x00007fae4ea58000)
...
```

The dat file is also in place -

```
ls -al /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1664511 Jan  3  2012 /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat
```

Comment: What output are you getting? Have you tried `geoiplookup -f /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat 74.125.225.132` to see if your GeoIP data file is right?

Comment: geoiplookup -f /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat -i 74.125.225.132
GeoIP Country Edition: US, United States
  ipaddr: 74.125.225.132
  range_by_ip:  74.124.206.88 - 74.126.5.223
  network:      74.125.0.0 - 74.125.255.255 ::16
  ipnum: 1249763716
  range_by_num: 1249693272 - 1249773023
  network num:  1249705984 - 1249771519 ::16

Comment: Country location is only available on the terminal output. So assuming you are using the curses interface, did you hit `enter` after selecting the `hosts` module? what output are you getting?

Comment: Thanks for the input. This is how I am executing the command goaccess -f ./access.log-20130830. How do I 'select' the host module? For now, I have loaded the data into my PostgreSQL database and it is working fine (doing the lookup as a separate process). Still, I would like to learn to do this from goaccess command.

Comment: You should see something like [this](http://dev.goaccess.prosoftcorp.com/images/goaccess_screenshot3M-03L.png?1378347300) when expanding the host module. Note that the country is underneath each IP. Are you getting this screen?